# Verificar se GPS está habilitado em todas versões do Android?

Tags: java, android

Eu utilizo este código para verificar se o GPS está habilitado para que exiba um dialog:

```
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

mas só funciona até a versão 19 se não me engano, gostaria de implementar para que funcione em todas as versões do android, mas não consegui, alguém me da essa ajuda ai, vlw!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    }else{
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }


}
```